# C++ STL map::erase a non-existing key

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, key, erase

Regarding the C++ STL map, erasing by key:-

```
 size_type map::erase ( const key_type& x );
```

Is it legal to erase a non-existing key? i.e. is the snippet below ok?

```
map<char,int> mymap;
mymap['c']=30;
mymap.erase('c');
mymap.erase('c');
mymap.erase('D');
```

Cheers

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Yes, in fact, [`std::map::erase()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase) returns a size_type which indicates the number of keys erased. Thus it returns 0 for nothing erased and 1 for something erased for a map.

Answer (score 13):

This is perfectly fine, mymap.erase('D') will return 0 in this case.

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/erase.html